# How to consider syntax-whitespace while parsing PDF data?

Tags: parsing, pdf, syntax, whitespace

My question is about the syntax used in pdf files. Documentation    ([PDF32000_2008.pdf](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf),[pdf_reference_1-7.pdf](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf)) states what whitespace is:

> **white-space character**
>   characters that separate PDF syntactic
>   constructs such as names and numbers from each other; white space
>   characters are HORIZONTAL TAB (09h), LINE FEED (0Ah), FORM FEED (0Ch),
>   CARRIAGE RETURN (0Dh), SPACE (20h); (see Table 1 in 7.2.2, “Character
>   Set”)

**Note:** *Be adviced that whitespace refers to the data/content of the pdf file (i.e. when opened with an editor `vim`) and not the rendered presentation (i.e. when viewed in pdf-reader)*

To my understanding that would mean that this is a valid PDF object

```
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog 
/Pages 2 0 R
>>
endobj
```

where between the two objects of type `(name)`: `/Type` and `/Catalog` there is a `SPACE (20h)` character, fulfilling the quoted purpose to "separate [those two] PDF syntactic constructs".

However it turns out that I am able to omit the whitespace while still producing the same rendered results (in `pdf.js` and `evince` programs). Hence my question is this an equivalent alternative to the code shown above

```
1 0 obj
<< /Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is legal.

Right after the description of whitespace characters, you will find the following: (emphasis added)

> The *delimiter characters* `(`, `)`, `<`, `>`, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, `/` and `%` are special. They delimit syntactic entities such as strings, arrays, names, and comments. Any of these characters **terminates the entity preceding it** and is not included in the entity.

So you don't need whitespace before the `/`.